# How to deal with stateless Rest request

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, web-services

I have a web application and an android application. When a client uses the android app and sends a request, the webservice consumes my web app's services. For example

```
 @GET
    @Path("/req1")
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public String returnRes1(@PathParam("num") {
appService.method1(); //web service consume method1 of webApp service
}

@GET
    @Path("/req2")
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public String returnRes2(@PathParam("num") {
appService.method2(); //web service consume method2 of webApp service
}
```

In method one, we do some processing, in the next request when I execute methode2, I don't find variables (global variables) that their values were affected in method1. I know that Rest is statless. But is there a way to deal with this problem? I have to keep those variables. Note that my web app service has a scope session.

Comment: Try making your appService SingletonBean or ApplicationScopedBean.

Comment: If my appService is singleton, so i'll have problem when many users connect to the web app. cause singleton create one instance of service

Comment: If you want to share data/object/value between requests, you have to keep them in a larger scope than requestScope bean. So if you can't set appService as Singleton or ApplicationScoped, then you have to create another bean with one of these scopes and keep data in a map or list, depends on your data/obejct/value you use.